# How to make the loading page not show when going to the home page again (loading page code on the home page file)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I had a loading page code on the homepage file, and I wanted the loading page not to show when I'm on another page back to the homepage.

I wanted to use the loader page when first opening the website and when refreshing the page (only on the home page, not on anything else like about or etc.), and I wanted the load page to not show when I clicked the home page (because of the load page code in the homepage file).

```js
$(window).loader(function() {
  
    hide2.classList.remove('hide');
    $(".loader").animate({
        'top': '-100%'
    });
    setTimeout(removeLoader, 2000);
})

function removeLoader(){
    $( ".loader" ).fadeOut(500, function() {
      $( ".loader" ).remove(); 
}
```

```css
.loader {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.wave {
  width: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, cyan, #fff);
  margin: 10px;
  animation: wave 1s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.wave:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.wave:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.wave:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.wave:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.wave:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.wave:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.wave:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
.wave:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.wave:nth-child(10) {
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
.wave:nth-child(11) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.wave:nth-child(12) {
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
.wave:nth-child(13) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
.wave:nth-child(14) {
  animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
.wave:nth-child(15) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}
```

```html
HomePage:

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="counterNumber"></div>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li class="menu-item is-active">Home</li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="/article_n_others.html"> Article & Others,</a> </li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="/projects.html"> Projects,</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="/contact_me.html"> Contact,</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="/about.html"> About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main class="hide">
        <section class="landing">
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
        </section>
    </main>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
</body>

AnotherPage:

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script defer src="main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li class="menu-item is-active">Home</li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="/article_n_others.html"> Article & Others,</a> </li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="/projects.html"> Projects,</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="/contact_me.html"> Contact,</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="/about.html"> About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main class="hide">
        <section class="landing">
            <h1>Another Page</h1>
        </section>
    </main>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to work along with localStorage or sessionStorage for it. Let's say you set have set initialLoad property inside localStorage and every time you just have to check for that property inside if condition and update display/ hide style property for loader.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
         if (localStorage.getItem("pageloadcount")) { 
             $("#landContainer").hide();
         } 
         localStorage.setItem("pageloadcount", "1");
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is still showing the loader page when I click the homepage on another page. What I wanted is a loader page to show at first or when refreshing the page, but not shown when clicking the homepage on another page.

Answer (score 0):

use sessionStorage to save your loader state.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("loader")) return;
    sessionStorage.setItem("loader", 1);

    const hide = document.querySelector('.hide');
    const hide2 = document.querySelector('main');
    const loader = document.querySelector('.loader');

    hide.classList.remove('hide');
    hide2.classList.remove('hide');
    $(".loader").animate({
        'top': '-100%'
    });
    setTimeout(removeLoader, 2000);
})
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is still showing the loader page when I click the homepage on another page. What I wanted is a loader page to show at first or when refreshing the page, but not show when clicking the homepage on another page, because the page loader code is inside the homepage file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using `$().one();` jQuery function.

Comment: Sorry, but it is still showing the loader page when I click the homepage on another page. What I wanted is a loader page to show at first or when refreshing the page, but not show when clicking the homepage on another page, because the page loader code is inside the homepage file.

Comment: Try this one(not suitable for older browsers) `$(function(){
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("load") != "true") {
        //your running once code here.
        window.localStorage.setItem("load", "true");
    }
})`  If you would like to support older browsers, translate this into a cookie format, like this: `$(function(){
    if(document.cookie != "load=true") {
        //your running once code here.
        document.cookie = "load=true";
    }
})`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I wanted to use the loader page when first opening the website and when refreshing the page (only on the home page, not on anything else like about or etc.), and I wanted the load page to not show when I clicked the home page (because of the load page code in the homepage file). Sorry for confusing you all, guys. I was also perplexed as to how to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

you may try add a get parameter to your home link, parse it on server side to add or not your load code or access *window.location* string from js part to show your loading thing or not

you also could use a fake form with a dedicated post parameter and submit it on click with your home link

but as other answers, use session or local storage is easier, set inside it a specific data on your link click and drop it after it's existence check to show load or not

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.referrer` might be the solution.

The ‍‍‍‍‍‍`document.referrer` property returns the URI of the page that is linked to this page.

Check the referrer and based on it make your loader visible or not.